# Restore SSH Key from txt

Tags: ssh, openssh

I had saved my private and public SSH key contents to a text file, and I recently had to reinstall Ubuntu meaning I lost most of the stuff that was in my home folder. Now, I would like to restore my SSH keys from the txt file.

Here's the procedure that I'm using thus far:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub # copy/paste public key
nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa # copy/paste private key
```

But when I try to connect to a remote host that has my key, I get:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
```

Searching for that led me to try:

```
ssh-add
```

Which asks me to enter the passphrase, which I have and enter correctly, yet I receive an error:

```
Bad passphrase, try again for /home/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa
```

How do I fix this and restore my SSH keys from copy/pasted text?

---

#### Information Requests

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to SNIPPED [SNIPPED] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brandon/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brandon/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brandon/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brandon/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA SNIPPED
debug1: Host 'SNIPPED' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/brandon/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f80ce9c7630),
debug2: key: /home/brandon/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/brandon/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/brandon/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SNIPPED
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/brandon/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/brandon/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSH stores its keys in Base64 text format.  The fact that you can't provide a correct password tells us that at least one half may be corrupt.  Please post the output of your ssh attempt with the "ssh -vv" flag added.  The debug info may reveal more details about the problem.

Note that the .pub (public half) is one very long line.  If you stuck line breaks in there, it's no longer a valid key part.

Also, when you're recreating these files, make sure they have proper permissions:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

If you're not sure about the state/sanity of your .pub key part, you can regenerate it from the private half:

```
ssh-keygen -y ~/.ssh/id_rsa | tee ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you do this, note that you may have to manually append a comment to the public half, as that part is destroyed when regenerating the public key.

```
nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Go to the end of the line, then add a single space followed by username@hostname.  WITHOUT pressing Enter, save the file.  Make sure no additional carriage returns/linefeeds are added to the .pub file, or it'll be broken (again).

Assuming you've done all this and your id_rsa.pub still doesn't match up with whatever you have in the remote system's authorized_keys file, you're pretty much stuck.  You'll either have to find another backup of your id_rsa private key, or it's time to run ssh-keygen anew and start over with a new key pair.  In this case, look on the bright side - changing your keys periodically is a good thing. ;)

Comment: I've updated the question with the information requested. I'm thinking it's something about how I'm copying/pasting the information into the private key. It seems that character returns are stored as spaces in my backup.